# How do I pick Germany in multiplayer match?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

I don't seem to be able to switch teams or even select a team. I would like to play as Axis. How does that work?

Comment: Try to limit your posts to one distinct question.  As it is, you are asking two completely different questions. You may need to elaborate more on what you are asking with the second question as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are playing a public multiplayer match of any given gametype. As this isn't specifically mentioned in your question.

- It is not possible to switch teams during a match.
- It is not possible to pick a team before the match
- Both teams can be played. However are randomly assigned